# What is node/proxy subresource in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

You can find mentions of that resource in the following Questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230623/forbidden-to-access-kubernetes-api-server), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396607/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-kubernetes-api-resources-and-subresources). But I am not able to figure out what is the use of this resource.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's true, the provided (in comments) link to the documentation might be confusing so let me try to clarify you this.

As per [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#so-many-proxies) the apiserver proxy:

> - is a bastion built into the apiserver
> - connects a user outside of the cluster to cluster IPs which otherwise    might not be reachable
> - runs in the apiserver processes
> - client to proxy uses HTTPS (or http if apiserver so configured)
> - proxy to target may use HTTP or HTTPS as chosen by proxy using    available information
> - **can be used to reach a Node, Pod, or Service**
> - does load balancing when used to reach a Service

So answering your question - setting `node/proxy`resource in `clusterRole` allows k8s services access kubelet endpoints on specific node and path.

As per [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#control-plane-to-node):

> There are two primary communication paths from the control plane
> (apiserver) to the nodes. The first is from the apiserver to the
> kubelet process which runs on each node in the cluster. The second is
> from the apiserver to any node, pod, or service through the
> apiserver's proxy functionality.

The connections from the apiserver to the kubelet are used for:

- fetching logs for pods
- attaching (through kubectl) to running pods
- providing the kubelet's port-forwarding functionality

Here are also few running examples of using `node/proxy` resource in `clusterRole`:

1. [How to Setup Prometheus Monitoring On Kubernetes Cluster](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/)
2. [Running Prometheus on Kubernetes](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/running-prometheus-on-kubernetes)

Comment: It is worth noting that according to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/119640) finding, permission to the `nodes/proxy` resource allows privilege escalation and should thus be granted with care.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to find in Kubernetes official documents any information about this sub-resource.

In context of RBAC, the format `node/proxy` can be used to grant access to the sub-resource named `proxy` for `node` resource. Also the same access can be granted for `pods` and `services`.
We can see it from the output of available resourses from the Kubernetes API server (API Version: v1.21.0):

```
===/api/v1===
...
nodes/proxy
...
pods/proxy
...
services/proxy
...
```

Detailed information about usage of proxy sub-resource can be found in The Kubernetes API (depends on the version you use) - section `Proxy Operations` for every mentioned resource: pods, nodes, services.

Comment: Yes in docs there is mention of proxy https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#-strong-proxy-operations-node-v1-core-strong- but this doc does not explain what is the use of this resource? When to use this?