# Overview of kubernetes apigroup subresources

Tags: kubernetes

How can I get a list of subresources that can be used in an RBAC role?

For example, I know that `pods/exec` is a valid resource (discovered by searching SO actually), but I cannot figure out where this is officially mentioned.

`kubectl api-resources` gives me `pods` as a valid resource, but not `pods/exec`.

I'm looking at the Kubernetes API website (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/), but if that information is there, I'm unable to find it.

How are mere mortals like me supposed to find this information?

Answer (score 1):

I do agree that it does not give you much details. I had the same issue.

I came across this a couple of weeks ago.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51289417/2752291
```

Answer (score 0):

These apis are not documented officially. `exec` is an api with is actually exposed by kubelet. You can check kubelet [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go) to see what apis are exposed by kubelet.